# Horizontal StackView Spacing not working at runtime

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistackview

I'm having problems when using StackViews for laying out my views when device rotation changes.

I get good results in storyboard.

[image: Horizontal StackView with Spacing]

However it isn't working as expected at runtime; after doing rotation on simulator, search control size increments and space is gone! I even tested on a physical device.

[image: Horizontal StackView Spacing Gone at Runtime]

Comment: Post your constraints? Tough to figure it out without seeing them...

Comment: I had width constraint for the filter button; that's all I need I think. Problem is gone now! 
Fixed by myself by deleting and re-adding controls to the UIStackView, looks like it is not that stable; sometimes it might fail, so must delete and add them again. Have in mind that!

Comment: Sorry I didn't put many pictures @DonMag; I've not enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

I had width constraint for the filter button; that's all I need I think.

Problem is gone now! Fixed by myself by deleting and re-adding controls to the UIStackView, looks like stackviews are not very stable; sometimes it might fail, so must delete and add them again. Have in mind that!

[Width constraint for filter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkdoM.png)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed... Some quick searching shows it's not uncommon to see issues with `UISearchBar` -- suggestions include embedding the `UISearchBar` inside a plain `UIView`, and then putting the View and Button in the `UIStackView`. If it "flakes out" on you again, might be worth a try.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll definately embed it to a UIView. I don't think having an extra UIView will hurt :P
Thanks a lot @DonMag